# React Native: Android navigation bar color changes randomly on load

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

The android app navigation bar color changes randomly when the app loads from background. Some time the navigation bar color is taken from screen first elements.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change it using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation-bar-color

Comment: I have used the above package to change the default color to red. but still facing the issue. Currently it is white some time it is black or text of the screen

Comment: You can also try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navbar-color

Comment: Make sure you followed the installation and link library steps

Comment: The color changed but when app loads again same issue.

Comment: import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';

export default (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    changeNavigationBarColor('#CA001B');
  }, []);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text>q</Text>
    </View>
  );
};